# Generic map with wildcard

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

I need to store one instance of objects for some classes.
I'd like to create a generic map like this:

```
<T> Map<Class<T>, T> objects;
```

But it's not possible and

```
Map<Class<?>, ?> objects;
```

Is not what I want because I would like to avoid casts:

```
MyClass c = (MyClass)objects.get(MyClass.class);
```

Also, I'd like Java to forbid me to do this:

```
objects.put(MyClass.class, new MyClass2());
```

One solution is to create a custom map so I would have a generic parameter `<T>`, but is there a solution without creating a new class?

Comment: Where is the `T` coming from? You can't instantiate an instance of a type that isn't fully defined, so your type parameter has to come from somewhere.

Comment: I know the first statement is wrong, this is just ti illustrate the dependancies of the two parameters of the map.

Comment: If third-party libraries are fair game, Guava's [`MutableClassToInstanceMap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0-rc1/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MutableClassToInstanceMap.html) does _exactly_ this.  (But generally speaking, there's going to have to be a new class _somewhere_ to make this work, even if someone else wrote it.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman, it still implements the `Map` interface, so it seems that you can put everything there using `put` method...

Comment: It'll throw if you put in an object incompatible with the class key.  Though if you use putInstance, it'll enforce that at compile time, not just runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard `Map` interface is not suitable for such scenario. However you can implement your own class which parameterizes `get` and `put` methods delegating them to the private `Map` field:

```
public class ClassObjectMap {
    private Map<Class<?>, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void put(Class<T> clazz, T value) {
        assert clazz.isInstance(value);
        map.put(clazz, value);
    }

    public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(map.get(clazz));
    }
}
```

Adding other methods like `remove()` or `size()` is not very hard as well.

Comment: This is what I suggested in my question : create a custom map. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can, instead of using the map directly, put in these methods to access the map always. That way you put the casting into the method and you dont see it anywhere else.

```
private Map<Class<?>, Object> map = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

private  <T> T getMapValue(Class<T> key){
    return (T) map.get(key);
}

private <T> void putMapValue(Class<T> key, T value){
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

And also it will forbid you from doing

```
putMapValue(MyClass.class, new MyClass2());
```